# WebView Load Mht file in Android

Tags: android, webview, mhtml

I have mht file in android asset folder i want to load in webview but 
when i start the app its shows me some scrap data so please help me 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you find a viable solution?  I am facing the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it directly...however there is a workaround mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556059/display-mht-file-on-android).Hope it helps..

Comment: Hi leo, when i run the code and when i click the .mht file it shows a error in logcat TypeError: Result of expression 'doc.evaluate' [undefined] is not a function. at file:///mnt/sdcard/.mhtCache/97aa/webkitextensions.js:6

Comment: When you load mht file in webview, it gives you unstructured content..I did load a mht file in the webview and it did not give me any error in logcat..please post some part of your code for further help..