# Android: Display .mht or .mhtml in Webview in Application

Tags: android, html, webview, powerpoint, mhtml

We are developing an application in which we need to display a Presentation (PowerPoint) file (.ppt or .pptx)..
We have heard that no API is available in Android to display Presentation files within our application.
So we tried to convert that Presentation file to ".mht" format as we have heard that `WebView` is capable of showing .mht files and .mht can have Presentations also..

Now my question is: how can we view .mht files properly in Webview..?

We already have referred these links mentioned below:

[WebView Load Mht file in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929258/webview-load-mht-file-in-android)
[Display .mht file on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556059/display-mht-file-on-android)
[Android WebView -> Display WebArchive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12872043/android-webview-display-webarchive)

Somehow the links mentioned above have helped, but not as expected..
Any further help would be appreciated..

Comment: Is extracting the MHT a viable option? A MHT is just a zipped web page (html, css, images...). Can't you just unzipit and bundle it in yout APP?

Comment: You cannot view **.mht** files in the WebView and expect to omit the unnecessary padding characters and text (i.e. html headers footers, content-type and mime info).  That's just the way WebView works with .mht files...

Comment: I'm not sure what is in your PowerPoint presentation... but could you just export the PPT(X) file to HTML? e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6274299/6144

Comment: If your application works online, Microsot OneDrive is capable of serving the PPTX files. Just share the PPTX into OneDrive and get the code to embed it on any webpage.

Comment: Use should just use javascript libraries like "[reveal.js](https://revealjs.com/?transition=convex#/transitions)" to your your app. this will be simpler... Else you could use css transitions for animating page loads. Powerpoints are simple carousels with animations nothing else. Just use any carousel library like slider.js or slick.js if all you need is a swipe gestured slide transitions.