# How to load .mht file in Webview?

Tags: android, android-webview

I have an Android application that displays .mht file .In order to make that happen , I tried:

```
 webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", s, "multipart/related", "UTF-8", "");
```

But that displays unwanted content on the screen like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egVWT.png) . Does anyone have any idea of why the WebView does not show `.mht` file?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebView Load Mht file in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929258/webview-load-mht-file-in-android)

Comment: That workaround doesn't works for me

Comment: Try this: webView.loadUrl("file:///my_dir/mySavedWebPage.mht");

Comment: I tried that ..But its not showing images ...Also its showing mime version and all in the top..

Comment: Hi all I could remove the scrap data..But still its not showing the bullets and images..Please do help in this

Answer (score 0):

The WebView do not support .mht file type.

Note: The Opera Mini can open the .mht files.

Comment: This is more of a comment. Until you gain reputation to post comments, make sure to provide [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question, instead of misposting comments.

Comment: It looks like this is an answer to "Does anyone have any idea of why the WebView does not show .mht file?"