# How to archive webpages in mhtml format?

Tags: android, html, archive, mhtml

How can I archive webpages for offline viewing on Android?

What Im trying to achieve is the following:

1. User enters a URL.
2. Loader dialog pops up.
3. The webpage and its resources are downloaded and archived in mht format.
4. Loader dialog is dismissed.
5. The app displays the downloaded page.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: as for opening mhtml, you can refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556059/display-mht-file-on-android. Unfortunately I can't tellyou how to save it. I think that this format has some specification, and you can save it using that specification

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?