# How to load mht file into a Webview

Tags: java, android, mhtml

I'm trying to load the ".mht" file that I saved using

```
File file = new File(getFilesDir(), FilenameUtils.getBaseName(url));
    webView.saveWebArchive("file://" + file.getAbsolutePath() + ".mht");
```

and tried to load it with the following code

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "myArchive" + ".mht");
```

and this is what I kept getting

[image]

seems the Webview doesn't support ".mht" files so I tried using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21741778/13116405) but couldn't find the libraries they mentioned

I have searched everywhere for the solution most people are just throwing expired links that don't work as an answer.
hope someone helps me to achieve that

Comment: Use File.exists() and File.canRead() before you try to load your file in the WebView.

Comment: `"file:///"` That should be one less: `"file://"`

Comment: I did check if the file exists and tried both "file:///" and "file://" as well, still, it's doesn't work

Comment: File.canRead() ? I asked that before.

Comment: just check again seems it can't find the file in this path "file:///storage/emulated/0/myArchive.mht" even if it exists there, I added the file.canRead(); it doesn't load anything

Comment: Please post your code. You cannot use a string like  "file:///storage/emulated/0/myArchive.mht" for File.exists() and File.canRead().

Answer (score 1):

you need:

```
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
```